# Oracle view creation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a  case like in the below picture

[image].

In the input table, each value under name column should have five steps A,B,C,D,E....But the name "VINOD" has 3 values A,B,C and their corresponding dates are 28.12.2013,11.10.2013 and NULL. So, in the view, i should have five diffrenet columns for each name as below. Since, "Vinod" does not have D and E, the corresponding dates should be seens NA( but since C value is NULL in table, it should be viewed as NULL only).

Hope i explained my query. Kindly help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: nope...it is part of my work. Since the values are sensitive to company, am giveing an example simiklar to the original values

Comment: okok, it seemed to my a typical DB problem, ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT name, 
       (CASE WHEN A_DATE IS NULL THEN 'NA' ELSE A_DATE END) as A_DATE, 
       (CASE WHEN B_DATE IS NULL THEN 'NA' ELSE B_DATE END) as B_DATE, 
       (CASE WHEN C_DATE IS NULL THEN 'NA' ELSE C_DATE END) as C_DATE, 
       (CASE WHEN D_DATE IS NULL THEN 'NA' ELSE D_DATE END) as D_DATE, 
       (CASE WHEN E_DATE IS NULL THEN 'NA' ELSE E_DATE END) as E_DATE
  FROM (
        SELECT name,
               (SELECT date
                  FROM inputtable as i2
                 WHERE i2.name=i1.name
                   AND i2.step = 'A') as A_DATE,
               (SELECT date
                  FROM inputtable as i3
                 WHERE i3.name=i1.name
                   AND i3.step = 'B') as B_DATE,
               (SELECT date
                  FROM inputtable as i4
                 WHERE i4.name=i1.name
                   AND i4.step = 'C') as C_DATE,
               (SELECT date
                  FROM inputtable as i5
                 WHERE i5.name=i1.name
                   AND i5.step = 'D') as D_DATE,
               (SELECT date
                  FROM inputtable as i6
                 WHERE i6.name=i1.name
                   AND i6.step = 'E') as E_DATE
         FROM inputtable as i1
        GROUP BY name
       ) s1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot..But where we are setting D and E date to 'NA' here

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mix data types like that.
Using the following test case:

```
-- drop table input_table;

create table input_table(
   name      varchar2(20) not null
  ,step      varchar2(10) not null
  ,step_date varchar2(10)
); 

insert into input_table(name, step, step_date) values('VINOD', 'A', '28.12.013');
insert into input_table(name, step, step_date) values('VINOD', 'B', '11.10.2013');
insert into input_table(name, step, step_date) values('VINOD', 'C', null);

commit;
```

The following (horrible) query should do what you ask for:

```
select name 
    -- If a row exists (has flag) pick whatever value was there, otherwise set NA
      ,case when max(a_flag) = 'A' then max(a_date) else 'NA' end as a_date  
      ,case when max(b_flag) = 'B' then max(b_date) else 'NA' end as b_date
      ,case when max(c_flag) = 'C' then max(c_date) else 'NA' end as c_date
      ,case when max(d_flag) = 'D' then max(d_date) else 'NA' end as d_date
      ,case when max(e_flag) = 'E' then max(e_date) else 'NA' end as e_date
  from (select name
            -- Pivot the dates to columns
              ,case when step = 'A' then step_date end as a_date
              ,case when step = 'B' then step_date end as b_date
              ,case when step = 'C' then step_date end as c_date
              ,case when step = 'D' then step_date end as d_date
              ,case when step = 'E' then step_date end as e_date
            -- Create flags because we have two kinds of NULL...
              ,case when step = 'A' then 'A' end as a_flag
              ,case when step = 'B' then 'B' end as b_flag
              ,case when step = 'C' then 'C' end as c_flag
              ,case when step = 'D' then 'D' end as d_flag
              ,case when step = 'E' then 'E' end as e_flag
          from input_table
       )
 group
    by name;
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the input. I cannot drop the tables since it is coming from the customer side. Anyhow, thanks a lot for the idea!!!!